# Angular URL 'trustAsResourceUrl' not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using [angular-file-upload.js](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) and uploading an image. When the upload is successful, it returns a URL to where the image is hosted, which is hosted as a blob on Azure. 
The upload is successful, and the URL is returned correctly, however when I push this URL on an "images" stack to view this image in the browser, it won't work properly. For example, the URL I get back looks like this:

```
"https://searlesmedia.blob.core.windows.net/event-images/4_slide-archive.jpg"
```

**Controller.js**

```
uploader.onSuccessItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
    console.info('onSuccessItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    $scope.uploadcomplete = "Upload Successful";
    var url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(response);
    $scope.images.push(url);
};
```

**Html**

```
<div class="row" data-ng-repeat="image in images">
    <img ng-src="{{image}}" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi it looks like you miss something please see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/1PpscI4dOMYpYRf6fbUS?p=preview

```
angular.module('mySceApp', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('AppController', ['$http', '$scope', '$sce',
    function($http, $scope, $sce) {

      $scope.image = {};
      $http.get("test_data.json").success(function(data) {
        console.log(data.url);
        // $scope.userComments = userComments;

        $scope.image.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(data.url);
      });

    }
  ]);
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example64-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.16/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.16/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>



</head>

<body ng-app="mySceApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppController as myCtrl">



    <div class="well">

      <b>{{userComments.name}}</b>:

      <img ng-src="{{image.url}}">
      <br>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I was definitely missing ngSanitize, but unfortunately still is not working.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with how I'm storing it in an array, because your method works perfectly fine.

Comment: Have you added reference to angular.sanitize.js ? Any errors on console?

Comment: please see here  http://plnkr.co/edit/1PpscI4dOMYpYRf6fbUS?p=preview I've crated demo for you with array

Comment: Awesome. It was actually ngSanitize, and also that I was returning a string back and not an object from my web API. Thanks for your help.