# Show pdf and docx in html using angularjs and AWS S3

Tags: html, angularjs, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3

I'm working with AngularJS and AWS S3 and I'm trying to view the files(.pdf, .docx, .ppt, etc..) in the browser but I'm stuck.

I'm trying to use the google docs view:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=MY_AWS_S3_URL&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

But I'm getting [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7Brpc.response.processed_url%7D%7D&p1=Error:%20%5B$sce:insecurl%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.4%2F$sce%2Finsecurl%3Fp0%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fdocs.google.com%252Fgview%253Furl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fpost-it-processed.s3.amazonaws.com%252Flive%252Fprojects%252F107%252Fresearchers%252F61%252F48108-Question%2525201%252520research.docx%253FAWSAccessKeyId%253DAKIAJJMX5FT4N5CABUVA%2526Expires%253D1506506184%2526Signature%253D8E82PPsd7xSJdhyOvQHfpI8h8Ik%25253D%2526embedded%253Dtrue) error in console's browser and obviously the view of this doc is not working.

Anyone know what is happening? Could be a S3 permissions error or maybe its because angularjs doesn't support it?

EDIT: 
I've tried this to show .pdf files and it works but just for .pdf files.

```
<object width="400" height="500" type="application/pdf" data="your_url" id="pdf_content">
  <p>ERROR!!</p>
</object>
```

Comment: Do you need to url-escape (percent-encode) `MY_AWS_S3_URL`?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I didn't understand the answer

Comment: The part of a URL after the first `?` is called the *query string*.  You are embedding a URL (S3) inside another URL (google docs), and this usually means that certain characters in the inner URL must be escaped using [URL-escaping/percent-encoding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to avoid what would otherwise be an ambiguity, e.g. using something like [`EncodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).  Are you doing this to the S3 URL when building the Google Docs URL?  If not, it may be needed.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  That's great, now I can view it in the browser, but it is still hide in the html, showing the same error that I've posted and now it looks more fault from AngularJS because of this: "Error: $sce:insecurl
Processing of a Resource from Untrusted Source Blocked"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, say thanks to @Michael-sqlbot for told me about [EncodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

The second step was made trustly the URL for AngularJS following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911626/angular-url-trustasresourceurl-not-working) thread.

The fact is, I had to made this to my S3 URL:

```
encodeURIComponent(my.s3_url);
```

And then I had to call $sce library to my controller (like I explained, we have to make trustly the URL for AngularJS) like this:

JS

```
.module('module.name')
    .controller('exExExample', [
        '$scope',
        '$location',
        '$sce',
        'info',
    function($scope, $location, $sce, info) {
    this.my.s3_url = info.url;

    // Here I encode my AWS S3 url
    this.my.complete_url ='http://docs.google.com/gview?url=' + encodeURIComponent(my.s3_url) + '&embedded=true';
    //Using a function of the library $sce called trustAsResourceUrl()
    this.my.complete_url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(this.complete_url);
  }]);
```

HTML

```
<iframe ng-src="{{exemple.my.complete_url}}" ></iframe>
```

And it worked fine, so I hope could this explanation help somebody like it helped me.

Comment: I'm glad you got past your issues.  Please consider reviewing [How Do I Write a Good Answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help center.  You should ideally include what you changed in your actual code, with explanations -- something directly useful rather than simply references elsewhere.  This answer might be considered a candidate for downvotes or deletion, for lack of substance.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Okey, thanks for the info, I've already it done. Hope could help someone in future.